# Setting label of prefpane dynamically

Tags: javascript, firefox, xul

I'm creating a `prefwindow` which sets the label attribute of its
`prefpane`s using JavaScript.
But however, it seems that this doesn't work, the labels in the
toolbar stays the same as they were assigned using XUL.

Any suggestions on how to work around it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The buttons are created when the `<prefwindow>` element is initialized or when the `<prefpane>` elements are added, they aren't changed after that. So the best solution would be to add your `<prefpane>` element dynamically, after you've set up its label (via [`prefwindow.addPane()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/XUL/prefwindow#m-addPane)). If you have to change the label frequently then you will have to use a hack (find the button and change its label manually):

```js
var prefPane = ...;
var button = document.getAnonymousElementByAttribute(document.documentElement,
                                                     "pane",
                                                     prefPane.id);
if (button)
  button.setAttribute("label", prefPane.label);
```